# How to convert Expression<Func<T, object>> to Expression<Func<object, object>>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees, linq-expressions

Is there way to convert `Expression<Func<T, object>>` to `Expression<Func<object, object>>` ?

Comment: Casting `T` to be `object`? Like `(object)T`

Comment: How exactly i should do it? I'm getting `Expression<Func<TNameSource, object>> nameSelector` and i need to pass that `nameSelector` as  `Expression<Func<object, object>>` to another function

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do this before...

```
public static class ExpressionHelper {
    public static Expression<Func<object,object>> ConvertParameterToObject<T>(this Expression<Func<T,object>> source){
             return source.ReplaceParametersWithBase<T,object,object>();
    }

    public static Expression<Func<TBase,TResult>> ReplaceParameterWithBase<T,TResult,TBase>(this Expression<Func<T,TResult>> lambda)
        where T :TBase
    {
        var param = lambda.Parameters.Single();
        return (Expression<Func<TBase,TResult>>)
            ParameterRebinder.ReplaceParameters(new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression>
                                                {
                                                    { param, Expression.Parameter(typeof (TBase), param.Name) }
                                                }, lambda.Body);
    }
}


public class ParameterRebinder : ExpressionVisitor
{

    private readonly Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map;



    public ParameterRebinder(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map)
    {

        this.map = map ?? new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression>();

    }



    public static Expression ReplaceParameters(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map, Expression exp)
    {

        return new ParameterRebinder(map).Visit(exp);

    }



    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression p)
    {

        ParameterExpression replacement;

        if (map.TryGetValue(p, out replacement))
        {

            p = replacement;

        }

        return base.VisitParameter(p);

    }

}
```

Comment: tryin gto use your function it gives error at `return new ParameterRebinder(map).Visit(exp);` with error message : Property 'System.String NewDescription' is not defined for type 'System.Object'.

Comment: That error makes sense.  You have no way of knowing what type the object was once you replace the parameters, so the member will not be defined.  In this case, you're going to need to  might need to just do a `Compile()`, cast and invoke like `Expression<Func<object, object>> toObj = x => stronglyTyped.Compile()((T)x)`

Comment: I ve tried to answer to this problem myself and ended with the same solution. Converting wont succeed on expressions that use its parameters like other type than object.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
static Expression<Func<object,object>> ConvertFunction<T>(Expression<Func<T,object>> function)      
{
    ParameterExpression p=Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<object,object>>
    (
        Expression.Invoke(function,Expression.Convert(p,typeof(T))), p
    );
}
```

Then you can say something like this:

```
Expression<Func<string,object>> foo=s=>s.Length;
Expression<Func<object,object>> bar=ConvertFunction(foo);

var call=bar.Compile();
Console.Write(call("hello")) ; // Prints 5
```

Comment: is there any difference between this and `return x => function.Compile()((T)x)`?

Comment: this approach changes Expression from `{o => o.NewDescription}` to `{Param_0 => Invoke(o => o.NewDescription, Convert(Param_0))}` is there way to keep same expression?